# Need to print content of the text file in email body using BLAT

Tags: powershell, batch-file

My script output can have more than one fields as empty, I moved value of "Name" to a txt file as below:

```
Select-Object -Expand Name | out-file D:\tmp\test\out.txt
```

Now I need to email text present in out.txt and i tried below command

```
blat out.txt -to email@email.com -subject "Field missing" -body "Field missing"
```

With this, I am getting email but, text present in file is not coming via email. Please note, I dont want as attachment in email.

Please help to fix it.

Comment: In Powershell, why not use [`Send-MailMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage)?

Comment: Why do you store to a file if you want to pass the data to blat? Get it into a variable (if multiple lines join them) and insert the variable into the body paramater.

Comment: Need to use BLAT only.  @LotPings. can you help with code how it can be done.

Comment: Weird that you're allowed to use third-party tools, but not something that's built into Windows.

Comment: "Need to use BLAT only" - why? IMO you need to provide a justification for this statement since `Send-MailMessage` is built into PowerShell.

Comment: See [Blat options](http://www.blat.net/syntax/syntax.html) Your usage of options is ambiguous. **Either use** `filename` **OR** use a minus and `-body`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late but to answer:

Your command should work but to troubleshoot further try adding other parameters and logging like below.

```
blat.exe out.txt -server "mail.server.com" -port "25" -s "Field missing" -f "your-email@email.com" -to "to-email@email.com" -log blat.LOG -debug -timestamp
```

Source: [enter link description here](https://www.blat.net/syntax/syntax.html)